# Checking for same condition with incremented value over and over again

Tags: java, integer, range, conditional-statements, increment

I am currently creating a very basic RPG game in java. I am currently working on collision, and this brings me to collision checking and my question:

Is it possible to check for a condition on 'foo' and 'foo' incremented a lot of times without making a mess like this

`if(!Level.getTile((x) / 16, (y-8) / 16).solid() && !Level.getTile((x+1) / 16, (y-8) / 16).solid() && !Level.getTile((x+2) / 16, (y-8) / 16).solid())`

Comment: if ` foo + 1 < getTile(x, y).x` then `foo < getTile(x, y).x ` is also true. Why do you need to test both?

Comment: I added the 'real scenario' from my code

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the methods `Level.getTile` and `solid`. Depending on how it works, there may be possible to have an efficient implementation of

```
boolean Level.isAnyTileSolid(int y, int x, ....)
```

That is, a method that takes one y value and several x values.

Comment: Let me use a simpler example:
`if(x != foo && x + 1 != foo && x + 2 != foo)...`
I just wanted to hear wether its possible or not

Comment: If x is an `int`, then `if (foo < x || foo > x+2)`

Comment: Still not what im looking for, take a look at the scenario in my question: I want to make sure, that the player will be stopped by every single pixel of the tile, being 16 pixels. Thats why i want to check to see, if it is indeed not colliding with any of the 16 pixels

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to explain -- you need to implement a higher level operation, the language cannot do it for you.